# JSON.Parse() gives me an error with a file saved in ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, json

My JSON file is saved with ISO-8859-1 charset. When I try to parse it using JSON.Parse(), I've got an error "unexpected token o on line 1".
Saving my file in UTF-8 solves the problem. Is there a way to avoid this extra saving and make parsing working with ISO-8859-1 ?

Comment: how do you read the file?

Comment: @Theolodis : I use readFile() from Node.js' filesystem module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is, that you don't seem to correctly read the data from the file. And in fact, Node.js's [`readFile`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) accepts an encoding as optional parameter.

If we do now [check the supported encodings](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/5a5a98d0d8281f6901b7e9dac285d59ab3e39b95/lib/buffer.js#L126), we notice that `ISO-8859-1` ([alias `latin1`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)) is not supported.

**How to solve your problem:**

1. save your file with a [supported encoding](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/5a5a98d0d8281f6901b7e9dac285d59ab3e39b95/lib/buffer.js#L126).
2. correct the encoding of the file after reading it, for example with the help of [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite)

Sample of a correctly reading function with the help of iconv-lite:

```
var iconvlite = require('iconv-lite');

function readFileSync_encoding(filename, encoding) {
    var content = fs.readFileSync(filename);
    return iconvlite.decode(content, encoding);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. iconv-lite does it. I didn't think about looking at the the source of readFile, sure I'll remember that for now.

Thanks